# Functions in R - General properties

Tags: r

I'm very new to R, I come from a VBA background.

If I understand it correctly, you cannot make procedures ( subs ) in R as you can in VBA or VB? How do I make a functino which just runs as a procedure? I'm trying on the code below, but is there any way it can just run as is, or do I have to have parameters within the function?

```
pgraf <- function () {

  library(ggplot2)

  dframe <- data.frame( x = c(3,1,5), y= c(2,4,6), label = c("a", "b", "c"))

  p <- ggplot (dframe, aes(x, y, label = label)) + xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL)
  p <- p + geom_point() + opts(title="geom_point")

  return (pgraf)
}
```

Comment: Give it a try.  Although I'm guessing you want to change pgraf to p

Comment: when I write pgraf in console I just get the whole function as is. I've changed p to pgraf

Comment: You've created a function, you have to call it, e.g. `pgraf()`.

Comment: ...also, it is often more idiomatic in R to `source` entire script files for this sort of purpose, particularly if the code you're running is fairly long.

Comment: I have gotten the code to work now, simple mistakes from me. Regarding sourcing functions, isn't this standard and the only way one can re-use functions?

Comment: One more thing, each time I update the code in the source, I have to refresh the source connection in the console before using it through the console?

Comment: No, R stores functions you define for re-use during your session. Functions are normally used for their return values, not their side effects. If you have a sequence of procedures that you want to save (a "code block"), you can put that in a file (without any reference to a function) and then `source` it when needed.

Comment: There are at least two mechanisms for storing functions and having them available in future sessions. You can put the code in `.Rprofile` or `.Rprofile.site` and they will be loaded at startup or you can put them in a package and load them with `library` or `require` calls from the console.